# Nifi ConvertRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a csv as input like the following:

```
a,b,c
alpha,154,1542
beta, error,6568
```

I want to use convert Record, to have an Avrofile. My issue is that one of the column as two types (int, and string).

Thus I have to give a full string schema for the CSV reader (and same for the Avro writter):

```
{
  "a" : "alpha",
  "b" : "154",
  "c" : "1542",}
  {
  "a" : "beta",
  "b" : "error",
  "c" : "6568",}
```

Is there a way that I can have only record with integer on a specific columns? With my method everything is converted in string thus I cannot discard not integer data.
What I would like to have is the following:

```
{
  "a" : "alpha",
  "b" : 154,
  "c" : 1542,}
```

I am running Nifi v1.9.0.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: TRY THIS - FetchFile (get csv) => SplitText (to handle INT/STRING record separately,  validate line by line) => ValidateRecord (define schema as per your data type requirement) => MergeContent (since we have split the csv, merge back validated records, discard invalid records )

Comment: Hi, thank your for your answer, which is a good idea. I will try but I am affraid of splitText processor as the file is quite huge (+300k lines)

Comment: Split by in chunk of 10K

Comment: what's the frequency of getting `beta, error,6568` kind of records
In 300k lines of csv, how much bad records needs to filter?

Comment: If I split by chunk of 10K, I will still have the same issue. There are few errors, I will say <0.1%.

Comment: RouteText/RouteOnContent processor is useful to filter records but writing regex is bit tricky in your case. See if any pattern matches to your filter criteria!